# Why the toISOString() applied on a Date object generate a wrong time section converting a date into a string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am going crazy with this Date to String conversion into a TypeScript project:

I have this function performing my conversion:

```
fromDateToString(date: Date) : String {

  let dateAsString =  date.toISOString().substr(0, 19)
  console.log(dateAsString);

  return dateAsString;

}
```

As you can see it take a Date object containing the following value:

```
Wed Feb 08 2017 07:00:00 GMT-0800 (Ora standard del Pacifico USA)
```

and, in theory it have to convert this date in the following string format:

```
2017-02-08T07:00:00"
```

But I am finding a strange behavior on the time !!! The generated string is not the previous one but it is:

```
2017-02-08T15:00:00"
```

The generated time section is not **07:00:00** but it is **15:00:00**

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Look at the full string `toISOString` is giving you.

Comment: Because of timezones. `toISOString` will always return the time at **UTC timezone**.

Comment: As per the docs, toISOString() always returns the date in UTC+0 timezone, so you have to search for a different conversion method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value isn't wrong; you're disregarding the timezone. [`toISOString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) returns a string written in UTC with `Z` at the end saying it's in UTC. You're stripping off the part of the string saying what timezone it's in.

If you like, you can get that string in local time instead by subtracting the timezone offset:

```js
function fromDateToString(date/*: Date*/)/* : String*/ {
    date = new Date(+date);
    date.setTime(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
    let dateAsString =  date.toISOString().substr(0, 19);
    return dateAsString;
}

console.log(fromDateToString(new Date()));
```

Just beware that your code using that string handles it as a local time, not UTC.

Comment: @Teemu - I...had the `* 60000` in it...at some point?! What happened? Some flippin' editing error. Thanks!!

Comment: @AndreaNobili - Through an editing error, the code wasn't converting minutes (from `getTimezoneOffset`) to milliseconds. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

`2017-02-08T15:00:00` -> this is UTC date (ISO) [UTC has 0:00 offset]

`2017-02-08T07:00:00` -> this is GMT-0800

so if we convert `2017-02-08T07:00:00` to UTC we need to add 8:00 hours so `7 + 8 = 15` so its giving `2017-02-08T15:00:00`

You directly cannot ignore timezone offset without adding/subtracting.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the EcmaScript algorithm for generating an ISO string always generates it with the UTC+0 timezone. You don't need (and shouldn't) modify the `Date` object. Here's an algorithm to get a ISO string with the local timezone:

```js
let toLocalISOString;

{
    const pad = function pad(str) {
        return String(str).padStart(2, "0");
    }

    toLocalISOString = function toLocalISOString(date) {
        const tzOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset(),
        tzPlus = tzOffset >= 0;

        return date.getFullYear() +
        '-' + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) +
        '-' + pad(date.getDate()) +
        'T' + pad(date.getHours()) +
        ':' + pad(date.getMinutes()) +
        ':' + pad(date.getSeconds()) +
        '.' + (date.getMilliseconds() / 1000).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) +
        (tzPlus ? "+" + pad(tzOffset / 60) : "-" + pad((tzOffset / 60).toString().slice(1))) +
        ":" + pad((tzOffset % 60).toFixed(0));
    };
}
```